# Android Recyclerview is slow

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

This is just a mock to give you some idea of what I am doing. 
[image]

My recycler view has complex logic.  Let me point out them,

- View holder UI is complex.
- Loading banner ads after each 5 view holders.

My data is coming from network and I have been using Room + Retrofit + Paging adapter.

User experience is very bad. I need some suggestions. I believe there are 2 things effecting my scrolling function.

- xml ui inflation.
- Loading admob ads in UI thread.(They want us to do it in ui thread. still I dont know why they do this crazy stuffs. )

I need some suggestions how can I improve and give some good user experience .

Comment: It seems to me that the UI is not complicated at all.
It is expected that there will be less resources needed for the UI to be drawn.
There may be other causes of the slowness, but please use the Profile function.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no source code, I'm unable to try to evaluate the exact cause of this. But I experienced something like this before, I have some possible solution for you.

**1) Move long-running task away from UI thread:**

I noticed that your data is coming from Room + Retrofit. By default, Room must operate in async manner, unless `allowMainThreadQueries()` is called. If you did called `allowMainThreadQueries()`, you can check your code if you accidentally trying to fetch data on UI thread.

**2) Did you implement RecyclerView (RV) properly?**

RV reduces the amount of xml inflation whenever possible and improve performance by reusing the inflated layout for the same view type. So, if you only have 2 view types as shown in your question, RV will only inflate 3-6 of your layout (even if you have e.g. 100 items in your list) and attaches it to ViewHolder and then bind and recycle the view with Item as you scrolled through the list.
However, RV may perform poorly if implemented wrongly. One example I experienced before is returning position as view type in RV adapter.

```
public class SampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVItem.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position; //Never do this
        return items.get(position).getType(); //Do this
    }
}
```

So, you can try to check if any of your implementation/logic is wrong with RV.

**3) Use Profiler in Android Studio**

If none of the above suggestions resolve the issue. The last way I can think of is recording the trace using Profiler while u scrolling through the RV and trying to identify which call is time-consuming/blocking by analysis the trace.
More info: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler

---

*Additional info*

Lastly, may I know what do you mean by loading AdMob ads in UI thread. As far as I know, AdMob load and return ads asynchronously like `UnifiedNativeAd`. And only then you try to inflate and set your view using the data from `UnifiedNativeAd` on UI thread which is not really UI-blocking task